# How to retrive integer ObjectID in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go

**How to get integer id because I stored id as 1,2,3,4,..**

*is having any method to fetch record by using id as int not by hex*

```
// Grab id
id := c.Params.ByName("id")

//Verify id is ObjectId, otherwise fail
if !bson.IsObjectIdHex(id) {
    checkErrTypeTwo("ID is not a bson.ObjectId", "404", c)
    return
}
// Grab id
oid := bson.ObjectIdHex(id)

// Stub user
u := models.User{}
err := uc.session.DB(DB_NAME).C(DB_COLLECTION).FindId(oid).One(&u)
```

Comment: have you stored it as **id** or **_id**

Comment: Can you please extract a [mcve] from your code and provide that? We don't know what's stored in your database and can't tell how to retrieve it either.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand corectly you're looking to query by an integer **id** you have stored instead of the auto generated ObjectID(**_id**)

```
// Assumed imports
import (
  "log"
  "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
  "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
)

// some func scope

var id int64
// init for id
u := models.User{}
var db *mongo.Database = uc.session.Db(DB_NAME)
if err := db.Collection(DB_COLLECTION).FindOne(context.TODO(), bson.M{
  "id": id,
}).Decode(&u); err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err.Error())
}
```

Comment: yes, but you have imported mongo-driver, but i imported mgo.v2
and i had done using gin framework ...

Comment: i would really suggest against using unmaintained software. specially when its a driver for a technology that has changed quite a bit since 2016( last release of mgo).